# Java Generic Method Definition

Tags: java, generics, methods, definition

I don't know if this is correct.

```
protected <T> SimpleJdbcCall methodName(){...}
```

My questions is, why do you have 2 return types in a Java Method Definition? or I may be wrong and this could be possible.

Thanks, guys.

Comment: `<T>` isn't a return type, it's a part of "generic method definition" as you stated it in the title

Comment: Check [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). Basically they are used to parameterized the arguments passed.

Comment: Thank you guys, I found the answer. :D